# In GitHub can I create a branch from a secondary branch and then merged it to main?

Tags: github, git-branch, branching-and-merging

So I have the `main` branch.
I usually open a new branch to get some work done, let call this `branch_1`.

I have now finished my work on `branch_1` and open a PR to `main`. But while I wait I want to do more work. This new work will use the `branch_1` changes, but it will not mess around the same files, let's call this `branch_2`.

I have now finished my work on `branch_2` and open a PR to `main`, but this PR includes the commits from `branch_1`. And both PR are pending review.
Is there a way to have my `branch_2` PR not include all these commits, but still work on top of `branch_1` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `branch_2` is dependent on `branch_1`, then you have done things correctly. You need the commits from `branch_1` if you want `branch_2` to work, so you should include them.

If `branch_2` can stand on it's own, you should rebase it onto main and then submit the pull request. Use caution if rebasing when dependent on `branch_1` features. The rebase will eliminate the `branch_1` commits, but this may also mean `branch_2` is now referencing non-existent code or using features that don't yet exist.

If `branch_2` is dependent on `branch_1` and you don't want to have a pull request that depends on another pull request, merge `branch_2` into `branch_1` and update the `branch_1` pull request appropriately.

Comment: I am  using features that don't yet exist. Will exist after 'branch_1' is merged. But I want them to be two different PR. 
And while working I need to see the changes from 'branch_1'.

So best approach is to just what I did, and when its time to open the PR just rebase into main?

Comment: @JoãoSantos I think that is an appropriate course of action. But there are many options here, so I would consider asking someone involved in maintain the repo and approving pull requests what he would like you to do.